# Getting session error while set a session path in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

I am getting a problem to save session on codeigniter 2. I have set a custom path on config file but it gives the below error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56/sess_h42mvq29914ldjcisg2nknvp55, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Filename: core/BI_Controller_Diganta.php

Line Number: 41

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56)

Filename: core/BI_Controller_Diganta.php

Line Number: 41
```

The Code which I wrote is in config file.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
 $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
 $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
 $config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH   . 'ci_sessions/';
 $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;

 $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 900;
 $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

And BI_Controller_Diganta 41 no line is session_start().
Please help me. I am facing this problem for long time.

Comment: `php56` ? Catch up time

Comment: the vesion is php 7.3.3. Another app is running in this server.

Comment: If you remove the custom change does the session work again

Comment: Actually i couldn't  check with the default path due to my access limitation, that's why I need custom path.